# Downloading a local file

Tags: java, html, tomcat7

Files is stored in this location.

```
D:/uploads/component.png
```

This is the HTML code to download a file.

```
<a target="_blank" href="../{{att.filePath}}"><strong>{{att.fileName}}</strong></a>
```

But when I click on the link it opens up as in this path, which is wrong as it is not in the server.

```
http://localhost:9190/D:/uploads/component.png
```

How can I see the file in web browser, what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: you are mixing absolute and relative paths. for start, upload your file inside web server directory to get it using url.

Answer (score 0):

Though you are not showing your variables' contents, it seems your variable contains the absolute path for the file. Therefore you don't need to add relative parts (e.g. `../`) to the path.

Also, if you want to host a file for downloading, **you must make it available inside the hosted directory (document root).** You can achieve this in multiple ways:

**A) Simply copy** the file/directory into the document root. Then you can also use relative links if you wish (you have to change the variable!).

For example, you may have a structure like this:

```
public_html/
    uploads/
        component.png
    index.html
```

Then you can link the file in `index.html` using the absolute path `/uploads/component.png`, or using the relative path `uploads/component.png`.

**B) Create a [symbolic link](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/) to** the file/directory inside the document root.

For example if you create a symbolic named `uploads` in your document root for your `D:/uploads/` directory, you will have this structure:

```
public_html/
    uploads/ -> D:/uploads/
    index.html
```

This way you can still have the file physically at `D:/uploads/component.png` but it will be available also in `public_html/uploads/` and you can use the same paths as in method **A)**.

**C) If you are developing a webapplication** (it seems so, as you tagged Java and Tomcat), there is another option. You can define a controller method which maps requests like `/uploads/*` and implement it so it will read the file specified by the URI from your `D:/uploads` directory.